# Confused about the `struct objc_class` in `objc2`

Tags: objective-c

```
struct objc_class { 
    Class _Nonnull isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY; 

#if !__OBJC2__
    Class _Nullable super_class                              OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 
    const char * _Nonnull name                               OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 
    long version                                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 
    long info                                                OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 
    long instance_size                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 
    struct objc_ivar_list * _Nullable ivars                  OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 
    struct objc_method_list * _Nullable * _Nullable methodLists  OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 
    struct objc_cache * _Nonnull cache                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 
    struct objc_protocol_list * _Nullable protocols          OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE; 
#endif

} OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
```

This is the `objc_class struct`, does it means that `objc2.0` only contain `isa`?
The `Xcode9.2` is using `objc2.0`, where are the super_class, name and others stored?

Comment: Can you add more data about the problem? When it occurs? What you do before it happens?

Comment: The grammar and style has been improved.

Comment: This may be helpful: `http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html`